# What resource dependencies are necessary to implement a command, and why?

Tags: gui-extensions

In the documentation section [Implementing and configuring a command](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D5BC468C-3F8A-403B-8D03-D969A0C1369F)

Step 6 says:

> If your JavaScript code references Content Manager Explorer functionality, then under the cfg:fileset, create a cfg:dependencies element and fill it with two cfg:dependency elements set to the following values:

```
Tridion.Web.UI.CME
Tridion.Web.UI.CME.Commands
```

Further down in the Results section, the diagram shows the following resources:

```
Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME
Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Commands
```

In the [Power tools configuration](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Editor/Configuration/editor.config#47) there is consistent use of

```
Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME
Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands
```

In the absense of any better explanation, I'm assuming that these references are to JavaScript code in the GUI, although there don't seem to be any obvious files containing this code, and the Anguilla documentation doesn't appear to mention them.

So - what are the correct dependencies to use? Must they be case-sensitive? What do they refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 6 appears to be missing the "Editors" part. Do us all a favor and add a comment to that doc page, so it will be fixed :)

The correct names are Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME and Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Commands -- and although there may be JavaScript namespaces corresponding to this, it's actually a reference to the groups defined in the Editor.config of the CME.

The idea is that you define "dependency groups" as a list of files to include and then anyone can simply reference the name of that group whenever they depend on your stuff. The dependent code doesn't need to know the exact files needed and doesn't have to be updated if files are added/removed.

Hopefully that made sense. It's actually a simple enough mechanism, but writing it out makes it seem more complicated than it really is :)

Comment: Yes - it makes sense, thanks. That was just the demystification I needed.

Comment: Great explanation, Peter. Makes perfect sense. I'm confused as to why this isn't in the documentation (or more prominent if it is) though!